# Why can't I use a variable in an if statement?

Tags: pic, c

I am new to Pic microcontrollers and just started programming them.

Now my problem lies in this code:

```
unsigned char i;
unsigned char firstRun;
unsigned char secondRun;
unsigned char released;
void main() {

     unsigned char i;
     unsigned char firstRun;
     unsigned char secondRun;
     unsigned char released;

     i = 0;
     firstRun = 1;
     secondRun = 0;
     released = 0;

     TRISIO.B1 = 0x01;
     TRISIO.B2 = 0x00;

     CMCON0 = 0x07;
     ANSEL = 0;
     while(1){
              if(firstRun == 1){
                          GPIO.B2 = 1;
              }
     }
}
```

Why don't I get any output on this port?

I want the pin to turn on, but it doesn't.

I know that I have hooked it up right on the breadboard.

UPDATE:
Im using the 12f683, the MicroC pro compiler and IDE, and im programming using the MPLAB X IPE

It has worked with the line GPIO.B2 = GPIO.B1 inside thw while 1 block
GPIO.B1 is input

This dosent work eighter:

```
char firstRun;

void main() {
     TRISIO.B1 = 0x01;
     TRISIO.B2 = 0x00;

     CMCON0 = 0x07;
     ANSEL = 0;

     firstRun = 1;
     while(1){
              GPIO.B2 = 1;
     }
}
```

CONFIG:
[image]

Assembly:

```
_main:

;Forste test.c,3 ::                 void main() {
;Forste test.c,4 ::                 TRISIO.B1 = 0x01;
        BSF        TRISIO+0, 1
;Forste test.c,5 ::                 TRISIO.B2 = 0x00;
        BCF        TRISIO+0, 2
;Forste test.c,7 ::                 CMCON0 = 0x07;
        MOVLW      7
        MOVWF      CMCON0+0
;Forste test.c,8 ::                 ANSEL = 0;
        CLRF       ANSEL+0
;Forste test.c,10 ::                 firstRun = 1;
        MOVLW      1
        MOVWF      _firstRun+0
;Forste test.c,11 ::                 while(1){
L_main0:
;Forste test.c,12 ::                 GPIO.B2 = 1;
        BSF        GPIO+0, 2
;Forste test.c,13 ::                 }
        GOTO       L_main0
;Forste test.c,14 ::                 }
L_end_main:
        GOTO       $+0
```

Comment: what do you expect to get exactly? your code just turn on the pin.

Comment: I want it to turn on the pin, the probmen is that it dosent

Comment: Please update your question with which PIC you're using, which compiler, and which IDE (if any). Also, is this *all* of your code or just a part of it?

Comment: are you sure that the clock is configured properly? what if you turn your pin on before the while(1) and then turn it off in the if clause? how are you measuring it?

Comment: As well as Dan Laks' request, please indicate if you've so far been able to get any life at all out of this arrangement.

Comment: Yes  with the line GPIO.B2 = GPIO.B1

Comment: Why did you declare two identical sets of variables: one global, one local inside main() ?

Comment: Does this have something to do with the error ?

Comment: @user3541201  Normally, this wouldn't cause the error, which you are describing.  If there are 2 variables with the same name and different scope: one global, another one local, then a local variable will be used.  That's how a proper C compiler is supposed to resolve this.

Comment: Post the disassembled code. There won't be much.

Comment: What do you mean by 'turn on'? What external circuit is GPIO2 driving?

Comment: Hust a simple motor

Comment: I compiled your code with MikroC Pro and programmed it into a 12F683 with PicKit2. It works as expected when driving a LED at 20mA. How much current does your motor need, and how is it connected to the PIC?

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong. If you couldn't use variables in if() statements, programming would be pretty useless.

Comment: i know, ive programmed a lot of c++, but i dtill cant see any error

Comment: @BruceAbbott wow you really did that? OP owes you a beer.

Comment: @BruceAbbott At this point, probably version number of the compiler should be mentioned.

Comment: The posted assembly code is identical to mine, so I don't think it's a compiler issue. There might be a problem with the assembler or linker, but this seems unlikely. I suspect a hardware issue.

Comment: Well i actually downloaded microC pro from TheP i r a t e bay(shhh!), but when i tried this line GPIO.B2 = GPIO.B1; in  the while(1) loop it worked, so i dont think its a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

@NickAlexeev seem to have hit upon the problem- this compiler is non-compliant. See [this.](http://www.mikroe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20282)

If you get rid of the global declarations (outside of **main**), I bet it works.

I've seen compiler problems with global variables in Hitech C for the baseline PICs as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule with PIC's you should use the LAT register to set outputs and the PORT register to read inputs.  Try `LAT.B2 = 1;` instead of `GPIO.B2 = 1;`

*The syntax may not be exactly LAT, I haven't used a 12F part in probably a decade and I've never used the IPE, but it will be close to that.*

Comment: The baseline pics don't have the LAT feature- you just have to be careful. In this case, it shouldn't matter.